# Authorization Error handling with FirebaseListObservable

Tags: typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to catch an authorization error from Firebase/AngularFire using the catch method, but I get an error `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.`

The issue is when I do not have access to some data based on the authentication rules. When I am authenticated, the code works (without the .catch as this is a compile error).

```
Records: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public af: AngularFireDatabase) 
{
    try {
        this.user = afAuth.authState;
        this.Records = af.list('/Testing');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log((<Error>e).message);//conversion to Error type
    }
}
```

The above will work. However, if the `/Testing` is not accessible due to authentication rules, I then get an exception.  I cannot seem to catch this error with a standard try/catch.  I did see a reference to using catch though,

```
        this.Records = af.list('/Testing').catch(e => {
            console.log((<Error>e).message);//conversion to Error type
        });
```

However, this gives the compilation error above.

While I know that I can change the Firebase read permissions to allow anyone to read the data, I am trying to handle this error case to make my code more secure, in case someone gets to a part of the application that is trying to work with data, but the security does not allow them to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why catch isn't working, but you could try something like this. The second parameter of subscribe is the parameter for error handling, and subscribe has to exist on an observable.

```
af.list('/Testing').subscribe(()=>{}, (err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

Comment: This also gives a comiplation error: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'. Property '$ref' is missing in type 'Subscription'.`

Comment: huh. i would expect that to work. Hopefully someone with more insight than me shows up and gives you a hand, because i have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, thanks.  You have me on the right track though.  I used this to find another source that indicates I should not assign the results directly to the FirebaseListObject, but instead, push them in.  This works for a straight forward array, but is not working for an array of structured data.  I am investigating further.